# Handle primitive union types in JSON (de)serialization with Jackson in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, polymorphism

I know that there are a couple of questions around this topic already, but I still struggle to find a good solution for primitive types. I am trying to serialize and deserialize the following JSON data:

```
{
  "key": "key1"
  "value": "value1"
}
```

However, the value is a union type and could be either a boolean, a number or a string. So these are also valid inputs:

```
{
  "key": "key2"
  "value": true
}
```

and

```
{
  "key": "key3"
  "value": 3
}
```

What is the best way to serialize and deserialize this into a Java POJO? My approach looks like this (but obviously only works with string values)

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Request {

    private final String key;

    private final String value;
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Response {

    private final String key;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private final String value;
}
```

Comment: You need DTO to received the converted object. Obviously `String value` cannot hold a boolean. So you must show us your DTO first. Maybe you want to use `Object value`?

Comment: Where / How do I store the type information then during de(serialization)? I somehow don't setup @JsonTypeInfo annotations correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Request {

    private final String key;

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "valueClass")
    private final String value;

    private final String valueClass;
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Response {

    private final String key;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "valueClass")
    private final String value;

    @JsonIgnore
    private final String valueClass;
}
```